# How to set retry untill in karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I want to set the retry globally. So I have added

```
configure retry = { count: 4, interval: 5000 };
```

in `karate-config.js`. But after this, if I run the test, execution is not starting. However, if I add

```
configure retry = { count: 4, interval: 5000 };
```

It is working fine. How to set retry in `karate-config.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `karate.configure` API in karate-config to set it globally

```
karate.configure('retry',{ count:4, interval:5000});
```

refer [karate configure](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configure)